# DIVs won't resize for a width of less than 420px

Tags: css, html, browser, resize

I'm having a little problem with the auto-resizing feature!
I've already proficiently triple-checked (with the search-tool) that all my width-settings are set to %. There's nothing with a fixed width in the whole website. (Well, in fact yes, but nothing bigger than 100px, and in such case, not more than one per row).

But still, if I reisize the browser's windows by less than 420px width, the width of my body (html-body, of course :P) will stop by 420px and the well-known h-scrollbar appears.

Any ideas? Is there some sort of default-minimun-width? I've tried by setting a smaller body's min-width but with no results.

Just in case that's somehow helpful: the website is composed of an index (in html), two sets of three jQuery-script and one CSS files, which are alternatively wrote to the project when the site loads (one for desktop-browsers, one for mobile). I've already tried building the sites separatedly, with no better results.

Comment: This is a guessing game for us (without a short+working example), so the best tip I can give you is to learn to use a developer toolbar, e.g. [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox can be very helpful.

Comment: That's another interesting thing... when I open the Style-thing on the left from Firebug, the problem stops... when I close it, it comes again... so I'm not sure if Firebug will be of much help in this case

Comment: I'm sorry about the no-example situation... but the code is way too long... and to post little selections it's pointless, ain't it?

Comment: Agreed, it's good you don't post the entire code. Try to cut down (a copy of) your page to increasingly smaller portions, until you've narrowed things down to the bit of html+css that's causing the issue (=poor man's debugging). Most likely by then you've found the problem (and possibly the solution) yourself. If you have a small bit of code left and still don't see the problem then you have an excellent snippet you can edit into your question, allowing us to help you more directly.

Comment: Hey, is this the same problem as in this question? [Firefox 12 html element won't shrink below 376px](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755797/firefox-12-html-element-wont-shrink-below-376px)

Comment: @Jeroen: that's the kind of nice advice I was looking for! :D

Comment: @Mr Lister: didn't see that before... I think it might be a similar problem... I've tried the page in other browsers and seems to work fine.. so it must be the browser (I'd still like to solve the problem). As soon as I make some progress, I'll post news here! Thx everybody :B

Comment: I had the same ;P I switched to mobile to check 320px resoultion, but I think it's browser problem, not code problem, as far as I noticed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I resloved problem with Firefox. I think FF allows to shrink website to minimal width which need toolbar with website address, searcher, bookmarks and so on. I was testing on CSS tricks which is great site if comes to mobiles :)

At the first screen at 280px width toolbar stops shrinking as the website. Sometimes I have there also Firebug icon or Fireftp icon which makes my sites stop shrinking earlier.

[image]

But right click on toolbar and unchecked Toolbar menu. Menu should hide and site still shrinking on resize. Here is Firefox and Chrome and as you can see they are quite similar as comes to minimal width.

[image]

If anyone will notice that this soultion is wrong and didn't work, please give me a feedback :)